# How to check if a phrase is contained in the contentState?

Tags: draftjs

I'm trying to figure out if a certain phrase (it can contain a newlines or bullet points) is contained in the contentState of an editor instance.

How do I lookup if a text (“the lazy fox jumped\n over the \n• lazy dog”) is contained in the editorState?

Is there a helper/util method to do such task?

Can I get the offset of such a match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I lookup if a text (“the lazy fox jumped\n over the \n• lazy dog”) is contained in the editorState?
>   Is there a helper/util method to do such task?

One method would be to search the content string:

```
 editorState
  .getCurrentContent()
  .getPlainText()
  .search("your phrase") // -> index of match or -1
```

`getPlainText()` [has an optional `delimiter` argument](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-content-state.html#getplaintext) if that helps shape the content - and of course there are various string methods at your disposal as well as regex.